# Insert Unique PRNG into Db column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Is it possible to insert a unique pseudo-random number next to every existing record in a table?

Something like:

```
UPDATE Products P1
SET RandomId = Random()
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT Id
    FROM Products P2
    WHERE RandomId = [The same random as above]
)
```

(Yes, I'm aware that would just skip conflicts, not resolve them)

I'm aware I could do this iteratively through code or even in multi-line statement - but is there a single command which would do this for me?

NB: This question is for my own edification so Microsoft SQL Server and MySQL answers both appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Random float? Random integer? Between which values?

Comment: Random integer - No real upper limit beneath the maxsize but if it's possible to put a limit of, say, 1e9 that would be convenient.

Comment: To clarify, 1e9 = 1x10^9

Comment: @SchimtzIT Thanks, I hadn't spotted that one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never use random for that kind of operation. You need to use a sequence number. If you use random, you expect random like lottery :)

If you want to use unique random, you need to do something like:

```
select @max := max( RandomId ) from Products;
update Products set RandomId = @max := @max + Rand() + 1;
```

- 1 is there to make sure that Rand does not return zero.

Or you can create a loop that might not end in 3 times the age of the universe :)

Comment: Thanks for answering but why would I want a sequence in this (fictitious) case? That aside, your solution has one slight issue which is that it will eat up the addressable space - possibly very quickly - and never back-fill the gaps. Unless I've misunderstood?

Comment: I should also have mentioned that this is multiple statements and if I wanted to do that, I'd just generate a random, check it doesn't exist then use it - What I want to know is if it's possible to Update (or Insert) a Unique Rnd in one operation.

Comment: You want to do too many things in one query:
1. you want to fill the spaces.
2. you want to use one query.
3. you want to check for duplicates.
4. you don't want to use sequence.

the answer is no specifically for (3).

Comment: I suspect you may well be right - I'll leave this open a little longer to see if someone else has any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT NEWID()
```

load it into a variable since you have to use the same value more than one time.

Comment: To clarify, the question came up as someone I know is planning to do this to abstract part number from multiple manufacturers. Because of this, the numbers will be used (in his case) over the phone. There are a hundred solutions that will work but I wanted to expand my knowledge of SQL.